# jQuery document ready not working when resizing elements

Tags: jquery, height, document-ready

When I run the following snippet I try to get the height of the div id = 'imgLeft'.  Sometimes it returns 18 and sometimes it returns correctly with 238.375.  I also made the image clickable and whenever you click on the image it returns correctly with 238.375

The js code is at the bottom of the the html code.

Most of the time I get the correct answer in the snippet but it never works correctly on my site.  The code is identical.  Here's a link to the site: [https:www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/work.html](http://https:www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/work.html)

```css
#imgLeft,img,html,body{
width:375px;
max-width:375px;
}


div{
max-width:375px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" >
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!--  <script src="../js/mobileNav2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mobileNav3.css?test=applesuckbigtimes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home3.css?test=applesucksbig">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mobileFooter3.css?test=applesuck"> -->
        
        <script src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/js/mobileNav2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/css/mobileNav3.css?test=applesuckbigtimes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/css/home3.css?test=applesucksbig">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/css/mobileFooter3.css?test=applesuck">
        
        <title>work</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top" >
        <div id='header'>
            <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/images/swag-logo.jpg" alt='logo'>
            <div id='text'>Educate Inititiate Collaborate</div>
        </div>
        <section class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-mobile">
                        <a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">About Us</a>
                            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#!">Our Story</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Our Work</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">SWAG Leaders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">In the News</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Take Action</a>
                            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#!">Get Involved</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Donate</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Resources</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div id="socialMsgs">
                    <a href="mailto:swag@sustainablewestonma.org"><img class="fa" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/mail3-blue.png" alt="mail"></a>
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1960906387454685/"><img class="fa facebook" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/facebook-square-brands-blue.png" alt="FB"></a>
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://twitter.com/Weston_SWAG"><img class="fa twitter" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/twitter-square-brands-blue.png" alt="TW"></a>
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://instagram.com/sustainablewestonactiongroup/"><img class="fa instagram" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/instagram-brands-blue.png"  alt="IS"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div id="container">

            <div id="vision" style="display:none!important">
                <span id="v1">Our Vision:</span><span id="v2">A healthy thriving sustainable community</span>
            </div>
            <!-- left -->
            <div id="majorFlex">
                <div id='left' class="noflex panel">
                    <div class='scrollContent'>
                       <a class='left' href="#">&nbsp;</a>    
                       <span class="nf1">Campaign Highlight</span>
                       <a class = right href='#center'>&darr;</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="imgLeft" onclick="myFunction()">
                        <img id='xxx' src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/uploads/2019DarlingFamily_20200411_5e91f99243017701660809.jpg" alt="Highlight">
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <!--    <span class="imgCaption">Annual Town Clean Up</span>
                            <span class="nf2">Join us for the third Annual Town Cleanup!<br/>Every bit of help counts to keep our town beautiful!</span>
                            <div class="readme">
                                <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-work-detail/?tag=ACU2020" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></span>
                            </div>  -->
                    <div class='homeTextFMT'>        
                        <span class="imgCaption">Annual Town Clean Up</span>
                        <span class="nf2">Join us for the third Annual Town Cleanup!<br/>Every bit of help counts to keep our town beautiful!</span>
                        <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-work-detail/?tag=ACU2020" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
                <!-- center -->
                <div id='center' class="noflex panel">
                    <div class='scrollContent'>
                       <a class='left' href="#left">&uarr;</a>    
                       <span class="nf1">Featured Action</span>
                       <a class = right href='#minorflex'>&darr;</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="imgCenter">
                        <img src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/uploads/Earth-Month_20200411_5e91f992437c3354440328.jpg" alt="Aaction">
                    </div>
                    <span class="imgCaption">April is Earth Month!</span><span class="nf2">Follow us for daily tips on how you<br>can do your part to help our planet!</span>
                    <div class="readme">
                        <span><a href="https://instagram.com/sustainablewestonactiongroup/" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- right -->
                <div id="minorflex" class='panel'>
                    <div class='scrollContent'>
                       <a class='left' href="#center">&uarr;</a>    
                       <span class="nf1">Get Involved</span>
                       <a class = right href='#'>&nbsp;</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4links">
                        <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/get-involved/">Sign up for our<br class="wp">Quarterly Newsletter</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4links">
                        <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/calendar/">Attend an<br class="wp">Event</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4links">
                        <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/get-involved/">Volunteer with<br class="wp">SWAG</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4links">
                        <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/donate/">Donate to help<br class="wp">our work</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom" >
        <div id='footer'>
            <form action='#' method='post' name='myFooter'>
                <p id='ftCaption'>Help create a sustainable and healthy town of Weston</p>  
                <label>Join our mailing list:</label><br/>
                <input id='myemail' name='email' placeholder='Email...' type='email' required>
                <input id='mysubmit' type='submit' value='enter'>
            </form>
            <p id="cpyRight">Copyright © 2019, All Rights Reserved, Sustainable Weston Action Group </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>


function myFunction(){
var elmnt = document.getElementById("imgLeft");
var txt = "";
txt += "Height with padding: " + elmnt.clientHeight + "px<br>";
txt += "Height with padding and border: " + elmnt.offsetHeight + "px<br>";

var test = $("#imgLeft").height();
console.log(test);
console.log(txt);
}
    
    
$( document).ready(function(){  
    
var viewHeight = $(window).height();
var tops = $(".top").eq(0).height();
var foot = $("#footer").height();
var bots = $(".bottom").eq(0).height();

var panels = $('.panel');

for (let i = 0;i<panels.length;i++){
    $(".panel").eq(i).height(viewHeight - tops - foot)
   
};

$(".middle").eq(0).height(viewHeight - tops - foot);
$(".bottom").eq(0).height(foot + 500);
 
bots = $(".bottom").eq(0).height();
var middle = $(".middle").eq(0).height();
var panel = $('.panel').eq(0).height();

var imgLeft = $("#imgLeft").offset();



var homeTextFMT = $('.homeTextFMT').eq(0);
    homeTextFMT.height(panel - imgLeft);



 





  
   myFunction();
   
   
   
   


})







    


    
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What makes you think the image should be completely loaded before the document ready event?

Comment: I thought document ready waited for the html to be loaded, is that just for the html and not the files?

Comment: Nope. Read https://api.jquery.com/ready/ and https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: thanks, that took care of the problem. What's the right thing to do here, leave the question or delete it?

Comment: Give @j08691 some love - an upvote, whatever else you may do!